# symfony - admin module filters accessible as links

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am working on an admin dashboard, which will be mainly based on the current user that is logged in usingsfDoctrineGuardPlugin

What I'm looking to do though, is to have links in the dashboard, that are basically filters to other modules.

The problem is, I'm not sure how I'd do that.

For example, I'd like to have the following as links:

- List New Users - This link needs to list all users added in the last 30 days
- List Suppliers - This needs to list all users that are a group with a group_id of 2
- List Manufactureres - This needs to list all users that are in a group with group_id of 3

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Are all these different modules or one, admin generator or not?

Comment: These links are on the main admin page, dashoboard. The links need to filter users in sfDoctrineGuard, sfGuardUser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I truly don't think you should use filters in your case. Filters are temporary conditions to your data list. 
Here's a more elegant solution. We will reuse the functionality of sfGuardUser index action, and set its table_method "on the fly" (based on url).

```
//exetent the configuration class to override getTable method
class sfGuardUserGeneratorConfiguration extends BaseSfGuardUserGeneratorConfiguration
{
  protected $tableMethod = null;

  public function setTableMethod($name)
  {
    $this->tableMethod = $name;
  }

  public function getTableMethod()
  {
    return null !== $this->tableMethod ? $this->tableMethod : parent::getTableMethod();
  }
}

//now we need to set the tableMethod based on a route param (list):
class sfGuardUserActions extends autoSfGuardUserActions
{
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    //create a mapping between an url and table method
    $map = array(
      'clients' => 'getClientsList',
      'suppliers' => 'getSuppliersList',
      'manufacturers' => 'getManufacturersList',
    );
    $list = $request->getParameter('list');
    $table_method = isset($map[$list]) ? $map[$list] : null;
    $this->configuration->setTableMethod($table_method);
    parent::executeIndex($request);
  }
}

//create a custom url for your lists:
sf_guard_user_list:
  url:   /guard/users/:list
  param: { module: sfGuardUser, action: index}
  requirements:
    list: clients|suppliers|manufacturers

//and model methods for each of your lists:
class sfGuardUserTable extends PluginsfGuardUserTable
{
  /**
   * List of clients query
   *
   */
  public function getClientsList()
  {
    $q = $this->createQuery('u')
      ->leftJoin('u.Groups g')
      ->where('g.name = ?', 'client');

    return $q;
  }
  //and others
}
```

That's it. Now you can add links to your dashboard like this:

```
<?php echo link_to('Clients', 'sf_guard_user_list', array('list'=>'clients')) ?>
```

P.S. this approach now allows you to use filters (for their true reasons) on top of these lists. But, you will also have to adjust the appropriate links.

Comment: Excellent! I'll have a look at this today and see how it goes. This is pretty much what I wanted, simply links, that display a list of users based on their group

Comment: Ok, I have tried using with the users and worked great. But using the same code for other modules doesn't work. For example I've tried it on an `orders` table, but it always returns 5 records and not specific records based on my model methods. Any ideas why this would be the case?

Comment: It seems that `$this->configuration->setTableMethod($table_method);` returns null, but I'm not sure why...

Comment: can't really say, check if you extend the right classes. setTableMethod is not supposed to return anything.

Comment: I've extended the configuration file that my admin module created when I built the admin module. It does seem to call the code, but it returns all results in the list rather than the 2 records it should. I checked the dev toolbar and ran the SQL that my method creates and it returns 2. Just not in the list

Comment: well, if you are stuck. upload it to github, and give me the link. i will give a hand.

Comment: @Dziamid http://pastebin.com/1a2LpJ7C You can see my code, whcih I have modified from the one you provided above. The `getLastSevenDaysOrders` SQL output returns 2 records, but on the page shows 5. The `getLastMonthOrders` also shows correct from the SQL in dev toolbar into phpmyadmin, but on the page displays incorrectly. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, it seems I was returning everything, using `return $q->execute();` in my method call. I've changed it to `return $q;` and seems to work!

Comment: You made my day. I tore my hair for 3 days without figuring out how to do this kind of thing. Thank you very very much !

Answer (score 0):

Here is one issue: Admin generator remembers all filters data as user's attribute (read as "stores this information in session").

So if you dont care about all remembered data of filters, you may create one module that recieve GET parameters, set this parameters as user attribute (sfUser->setAttribute(...)) overriding filters data of needed module, and redirects to module.

Or

You may use GET parameters adding them to an module URL (example.com/users?filter[group_id]=123) that overrides filter params. At this case you should handle this information in each needed module.

Comment: Could you provide me an example as having: users?filter[group_id]=1 doesn't return anything