# Symfony - Need a form filter to accept GET variable OR other method to create a filter link

Tags: php, symfony1, filter

Using Symfony 1.3

I have a normal form-filter that is used to filter values of a list,
it works normally.  What I'd like to add is a link that is outside of the
form that can be used to filter by just a single criteria.

Anybody have a solution to this?  Is there a way to set a filter to accept a GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this in a much easier fashion than i suspected.  The request already accepts GETS.

I just created a link with the parameters set as array values.

```
echo link_to('link_text', 'module/filter', array('query_string' => 'module_filters[field][text]='.$object->getField(ESC_RAW)))
```

Clicking on that link does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this in 2 ways:

1. setting filters based on get parameters: [symfony - admin module filters accessible as links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679387/symfony-admin-module-filters-accessible-as-links/5728364#5728364)
2. setting table method based on get parameters: [Symfony doctrine admin generator list filters get method with no csrf token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900876/symfony-doctrine-admin-generator-list-filters-get-method-with-no-csrf-token/5904460#5904460)

I prefer second approach, because it gives you possibility to use filters on top your filtered list.